# Using Firebase in ListView displays only one row

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I know I know this is probably a duplicate of a few questions here, but hey, those solutions haven't worked. So i really need suggestions.
Been trying to use `firebase` to manage my `listview` but to no avail.
I have tried several tutorials around but none has solved my problem. 
I have a `listview` which i'm trying to populate from `Firebase`. I created a `custom adapter` and added `childEventListeners` there. Finaly i attach the `adapter` to my `listview`. I have several items in my `firebase` `database` but only the last one is displayed in my `listview`.I would like to display all of them.

FireBaseListAdapter.java:

```
public abstract class FireBaseListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SaleModel> {

    Activity activity;
    // Setup our Firebase mFirebaseRef
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    private SaleModel model;
    private String mUsername;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<SaleModel> mModels;
    private List<String> mKeys;
    private ChildEventListener mListener;
    private ViewGroup viewGroup;
    private LinearLayout wrapper;

    public FireBaseListAdapter(DatabaseReference mRef, Activity activity) {
        super(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mRef = mRef;
        this.mUsername = mUsername;

        mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        mModels = new ArrayList<SaleModel>();
        mKeys = new ArrayList<String>();


        // Look for all child events. We will then map them to our own internal ArrayList, which backs ListView
        mListener = this.mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

                Map<String, Object> newPost =
                        (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                model = new SaleModel(newPost.get("name").toString(),
                        newPost.get("attendant_name").toString(),
                        newPost.get("created_at").toString());
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                // Insert into the correct location, based on previousChildName
                if (previousChildName == null) {
                    mModels.add(0, model);
                    mKeys.add(0, key);

                } else {
                    int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                    int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                    if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                        mModels.add(model);
                        mKeys.add(key);

                    } else {
                        mModels.add(nextIndex, model);
                        mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                        //showNotification(model);
                    }
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                // One of the mModels changed. Replace it in our list and name mapping
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Map<String, Object> newPost =
                        (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                SaleModel newModel = new SaleModel(newPost.get("message").toString(), newPost.get("author").toString(), newPost.get("created_at").toString());
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);

                mModels.set(index, newModel);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                // A model was removed from the list. Remove it from our list and the name mapping
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);

                mKeys.remove(index);
                mModels.remove(index);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

                // A model changed position in the list. Update our list accordingly
                String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                Map<String, Object> newPost =
                        (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                SaleModel newModel = new SaleModel(newPost.get("message").toString(), newPost.get("author").toString(), newPost.get("created_at").toString());
                int index = mKeys.indexOf(key);
                mModels.remove(index);
                mKeys.remove(index);
                if (previousChildName == null) {
                    mModels.add(0, newModel);
                    mKeys.add(0, key);
                } else {
                    int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
                    int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                    if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                        mModels.add(newModel);
                        mKeys.add(key);
                    } else {
                        mModels.add(nextIndex, newModel);
                        mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("FireBaseListAdapter", "Listen was cancelled, no more updates will occur");

            }


        });
    }

    public void cleanup() {
        // We're being destroyed, let go of our mListener and forget about all of the mModels
        mRef.removeEventListener(mListener);
        mModels.clear();
        mKeys.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public SaleModel getItem(int i) {
        return mModels.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        SaleModel comment = getItem(position);

        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        // Map a Chat object to an entry in our listview
        String author = comment.getName();
        String attendant_name = comment.getAttendant_name();
        String created_at = comment.getCreated_at();

        // If the message was sent by this user, color it differently
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService
                (this.activity.getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.attname)).setText(attendant_name);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.c_name)).setText(author);
        ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.updated_at)).setText(created_at);

        return row;

    }
}
```

SaleModel.java:

```
public class SaleModel {
  //obviously there's a lot of things i'm not using here, so ignore these
    String id, business_id, attendant_id, attendant_name, product_id,
            customer_id, customer_first_name, code,
            customer_last_name, customer_image, uid,
            reader_id, price, quantity, name, image,
            created_at, deleted_at, offlineTag, updated_at, svg;
 public SaleModel() {
    }

    public SaleModel(String name, String attendant_name, String created_at) {
        this.name = name;
        this.attendant_name = attendant_name;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
//getters and setters
 public String getAttendant_name() {
        return attendant_name;
    }

    public void setAttendant_name(String attendant_name) {
        this.attendant_name = attendant_name;
    }
 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
  public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }}
```

And this is how i'm using it on my fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
   FirebaseDatabase ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("sales");
        setUpAdapter();
       final FireBaseListAdapter mChatListAdapter = new FireBaseListAdapter(ref, parentActivity) {
            @Override
            public void cleanup() {
                super.cleanup();
            }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);
        mChatListAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();
                listView.setSelection(mChatListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });

    }
```

And an example of my data Structure:

```
{
  "-KMjcAb5O2MOx_WrofUT" : {
    "attendant_id" : "93",
    "business_id" : "9",
    "code" : "9.146860413464",
    "created_at" : "2016-07-15 08:32:10",
    "customer_first_name" : "Unidentified",
    "customer_id" : "10",
    "customer_last_name" : "",
    "image" : "",
    "name" : "Black Forest Cake 2kg",
    "price" : "3500.0",
    "product_id" : "59",
    "quantity" : "1",
    "reader_id" : "93",
    "uid" : ""
  },
  "-KMjcAb8EQi3ujTpoJG1" : {
    "attendant_id" : "93",
    "business_id" : "9",
    "code" : "9.146860413465",
    "created_at" : "2016-07-15 08:32:10",
    "customer_first_name" : "Unidentified",
    "customer_id" : "10",
    "customer_last_name" : "",
    "image" : "",
    "name" : "Black Forest Cake 2kg",
    "price" : "3500.0",
    "product_id" : "59",
    "quantity" : "1",
    "reader_id" : "93",
    "uid" : ""
  }}
```

Comment: I get the impression that you've re-used a lot of code from the [`FirebaseListAdapter` class from the AndroidChat sample app](https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat/FirebaseListAdapter.java). While such re-use is fine, I highly recommend starting from the [one in the FirebaseUI project](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseListAdapter.java), which is a lot simpler *and* fixes quite a few bugs.

Comment: But aside from that: did you already step through the code in the debugger? Does your `onChildAdded()` get triggered multiple times? Do your array lists end up with the correct number of children? Stack Overflow is a very inefficient debugging mechanism, so you'll have to do that work yourself and tell us. It also would help if you reduce the problem to something smaller. E.g. I expect you'll have the same problem with a simple list of strings. Having a **minimal** reproduction may take more effort from you, but allows us to more quickly focus on the things that are likely causing the problem.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen yes i did reuse most of the code from there :) Problem is i cannot seem to replicate the results. Also yes, my OnChildAdded does get triggered more than once? Sorry for my lack of simplcity, i jus got frustrated since yesterday. Logging the events OnChildAdded, i noticed that my arraylist size is bigger than what i display on my Listview.

Comment: Good good. There is no need to apologize for the complex question, just simplify it. If you do that, you're more likely to get help (and you're likely to already find the problem yourself). See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
From what just said, you can probably also reproduce the problem without Firebase. Just dynamically adding results to an ArrayList. That rules out the entire Firebase interaction and significantly simplifies your debugging. Keep reducing until you find the cause, or post the reduced code here if you can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop this section of your code as below. Hope this helps you.

```java
 Map < String, Object > newPost =
   (Map < String, Object > ) dataSnapshot.getValue();
 for (Object posts: newPost.values()) {
   Map < String, Object > postMap = (Map < String, Object > ) posts;
   model = new SaleModel(postMap.get("name").toString(),
     postMap.get("attendant_name").toString(),
     postMap.get("created_at").toString());
   String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();

   // Insert into the correct location, based on previousChildName
   if (previousChildName == null) {
     mModels.add(0, model);
     mKeys.add(0, key);

   } else {
     int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
     int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
     if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
       mModels.add(model);
       mKeys.add(key);

     } else {
       mModels.add(nextIndex, model);
       mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);
       //showNotification(model);
     }
   }
 }
```